# What does it mean for a polynomial to be positive semi-definite?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, positive-semidefinite

I'm reading proofs about Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Some of them use the argument of a polynomial being positive semi-definite as the starting argument.

That is, they argue that

$$\forall x,y \in\mathbb{R^n}, a\in\mathbb{R}\\\langle {ax+y,ax+y} \rangle$$

Is a positive semi-definite polynomial (when expanded). 
How is this seen?

There's one proof [here](https://books.google.fi/books?id=IPvJKTp2O7sC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=cauchy%20schwarz%20x*y%5E2&source=bl&ots=cBuwg3_T_e&sig=FQLu9mZIdgwz2EhyXVPTk8Xt_pU&hl=fi&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwADgKahUKEwjo943Y6trHAhXFfHIKHa5xBEI#v=onepage&q&f=false) if you can see it (page 2):

Comment: The formula in center of your question seems to be incomplete. You might miss an equality or inequality symbol.

Comment: Is it a *quadratic form* that may be positive semi-definite, not any polynomial.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2779050/721644).

Answer (score 1):

It means that the expression $$\langle ax+y, ax+y\rangle$$

is always greater than or equal to zero.

This is true because the inequality $\langle x,x\rangle \geq 0$ is true for any element $x$ in your vector space.

Comment: Yeah I've heard these terms in linear algebra, but what confuses me now is the mixing of polynomials and vectors.

Comment: @mavavilj Positive definite can be a term applied to either a matrix or a polynomial, in this case it's a polynomial.